# How to get rid of the fungus infestation that comes from the caverns in Dwarf Fortress

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I unwittingly dug into the caverns and I immediately sealed it off:

[image]

but I noticed that the fungus from the caverns started to spread at an alarming rate. Currently, everything is covered in floor fungus and other species including the outside world:

[image]

What can I do to get rid of this infestation apart from burning everything to cinders with magma?

Comment: Which outdoor tiles exactly are covered with moss? While Im a bit fuzzy on the exact requirements for a tile to be moss/fungus-eligible, it really shouldn't be a problem since all it does is allow for indoor grazing, or for mushroom trees in big enough multi-z rooms like natural caverns. You can't really stop the "infestation", but far as I know it has no downsides.

Comment: I just don't like how it covers everything. It is more of a personal preference. I realized that those outdoor tiles are not really outdoor as they have tiles above them (the remainder of the mountain I dug into.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your best bet for dealing with moss is building roads, floors, or buildings over them, fending it off much like you would grass.

It might also be possible (though I'm uncertain it works the way I think it does) to expose a tile to sunlight, i.e. no obstruction directly up to the sky, thereby changing the tiles property to "[above ground](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Tile_attributes)". This *might* have the tile grow regular grass as opposed to the underground variant. I'm basing the assumption off the phrasing in [this wiki page](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Cave_moss) which says the moss spreads to tiles that are "below ground".